# How can I find a general term for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$a_0=a_0\in \mathbb N_{>0}$$
>   $$a_{n+1}=\left \lceil\cfrac{a_n}2\right \rceil$$

This question has a relationship with [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227839/mathematical-proof-for-long-term-behavior-of-a-sequence-of-integer-vectors) I posted but both can be solved independently, so please **it's not a duplicate.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$a_n = \left\lceil\frac{a_0}{2^n}\right\rceil$$